# Identify an animated childrens TV show from the 1980s about a girl sent to another planet

Tags: story-identification, animation

I am trying to identify an animated TV show for children that I watched as a child (younger than 6) between 1980 and 1986 in the UK.

The opening of each episode set the back story for the central character - a little girl - who accidentally ends up on a rocket ship which is launched to another world.  She possibly might be accompanied by either her dog or a cuddly toy, I am not sure - I vaguely remember it being her dog that escaped and got her trapped in the rocket while she chased after it.

The natives of the planet she lands on are generally friendly, and again vaguely I remember them having circular heads split into two (similar to the South Park baby).  The environment is jungle like.

Comment: could you check if this might be it? It's a long shot, I do not want to post it as an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jana_of_the_Jungle

Comment: @jo1storm I'm afraid not, there was definitely a little girl that accidentally stowed away on a rocket to another world. Thanks for trying tho!

Comment: Just putting this here to annoy people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Robo Story](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robo_Story) (or Myrtille and the Robots)

> Robo Story follows the adventures of a small, orange-haired girl called Myrtille and her dog Loufi. In the opening title sequence we see Myrtille chase the mischievous Loufi onto a space shuttle that takes off with her inside. The ship crash lands on a world known as the Green Planet.
>
> The Green Planet is inhabited by robots. In the original French version these were the evil Rotors, and the friendly Robors.

[Google Image search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=robo+story&client=ms-android-htc&prmd=ivn&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&fir=W47fZoKBemJ9CM%253A%252CXukyPJXSFjDuNM%252C_%253BD9JHrRWA7cuxNM%253A%252CIa6arD4z_Z15rM%252C_%253B0mbWoX06YlsapM%253A%252CTMLxZjCRJUSpcM%252C_%253BVarMUB0YdknzqM%253A%252C4-LeqF_2yl2p4M%252C_%253BSy6bRRW22koelM%253A%252CZyThs4E7u5G9PM%252C_%253BpBExG1I70HYWRM%253A%252CNjIHi21VsnzvkM%252C_%253B5bK3JmjkRKd_1M%253A%252CDa1ym87Ad0bHsM%252C_%253BmjdMn1_iJR2tVM%253A%252C4VDTRUFvMfVDjM%252C_%253Bf_k4yvCmQkT00M%253A%252CqviceKycd__s4M%252C_%253BfaL2u5LtEGsInM%253A%252CzFr4tnwBtaL8TM%252C_&usg=__Kmlr33IGXOKDdTmuQ-L2aFDW3lc%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4mfidl4nXAhWMHpQKHbPBBhQQ7AkIlgE&biw=360&bih=616#imgrc=_)

[image]

I loved this show when I was a kid, and would love to introduce my nephews and nieces to it.

Answer (score 1):

Could be 
[The Mysterious Cities of Gold](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122356/) , it came at 1982 and happens in the jungle.

Comment: Nope, not that one - I watched that again recently.

Comment: Ok, do you remember anything more? Girl's hair color for example? On which channel you watched it etc.

Comment: This opening has rockets and aliens, that is why I am asking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2G1-6WBWvzY