# Old cartoon with a red? robot in a desert and a girl

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, robots

I don't remember much except for a few scenes and it's been bugging me for a few years, because I think it had a really interesting story line; I just don't remember it. It was a show I watched on TV as a kid, maybe 15 years ago, but the cartoon is probably older.

I looked at similar questions and I thought it might have been [*Zentrix*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0876249/), because some elements match, but the animation style does not match. I'm pretty sure it was 2D animated, more anime style?

What I think I remember from the plot is that there were others that were trying to get/destroy the robot. Maybe because of a prism, but I'm not sure about this. I believe there was also a girl the robot was protecting, but the girl was also very concerned about the robot.

I vividly remember this scene where the red robot was in a desert and was standing on a hill, probably fighting. Also a scene where they were in front of a cave in the sandy surrounding and the robot was fighting. Another scene I remember was inside in maybe a ship/building on a metal bridge.

From what I recall it wasn't a giant robot, more adult sized.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F; lots of great details here.  What country was this in?  Do you remember what channel it might have been on?

Comment: Another question; is the robot humanoid-shaped, animal-shaped or more mechanical-shaped (like R2-D2 or K9)?

Comment: Is it possibly this https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172554/373

Comment: I watched it in the Netherlands, but it was not on regular television, but some extra channel that we paid for, maybe cartoon network.

Comment: I would describe it as a humanoid shaped robot. A more squared iron man(with no person inside) or like bumblebee if it wasn't a car. Not quite similar, but I don't know that many robots.

And it wasn't robo story. The girl was definitely smaller than the robot. The storyline seemed a bit more complex so I think the target audience was maybe (pre)teens.

Comment: Does this look like the robot you are talking about? https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F58LQ39NA2SI%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: The "prism" you are thinking about, did it look like one of those? https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimg1.wikia.nocookie.net%2F__cb20150128233125%2Fsonic%2Fimages%2F1%2F1c%2FChaos_Emeralds_Sonic_X.png&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: Did not look like that robot. In my memory the robot was more squared. 
And I don't think that's how the prism looked like.

Answer (score 6):

Probably [Casshern Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casshern_Sins)

1. The whole world is a desert wasteland
2. Casshern travels with a small girl named Ringo. She is concerned about Casshern

   [image: Casshern and Ringo]
3. Casshern originally destroyed another girl named Luna, which ended immortality. Now Casshern must destroy her again
4. The red robot would be [Leda](https://casshan.fandom.com/wiki/Leda), who fights Casshern several times

   [image: Leda]
5. The series aired on Cartoon Network in 2012

Comment: For the records, that show is emotionally draining and slow paced. If you intend to watch it, you should prepare yourself.

Comment: ahh no unfortunately not this one, although it does seem interesting. The one I'm thinking about was not animated like this. The robot did not have a human face. It was a robot face.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're thinking about [Gurren Lagann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gurren_Lagann)?

In a world ruled by the Spiralking Lordgenome, he forces mankind to live on isolated, desert islands which are pretty massive and have lots of hills. Simon, a young driller, is forced to dig with his friend Kamina, whom he calls "Bro", in underground villages, which were created to hide from either the heat of the sun or Beastmen, a wild race of monsters who operated giant mechs. Simon, while drilling one day, happens upon a glowing drillbit pendant that is used to power up a large red robot. The Gunman, as mechs are called, was dubbed "Lagann" by Kamina, and could barely fit more than 2 people, being just a head with arms and legs. After meeting with a girl armed with a sniper rifle,called Yoko, they hijack a Gunman and steal it, the 2 Gunmen together form one.

[image: Gurren Lagann]

Yoko has shown to be fond of Simon, and often tries to get him to convince Kamina not to engage in reckless or dangerous stunts. Together, the three of them venture out to the overworld, determined to defeat Lordgenome and free mankind.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

(P.S.: This was aired in 2006, which makes it, quite literally, 15 years old, even though the manga is older.)